# Conversion of String to double is not valid VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to vb and I'm having this kind of error in this code "Conversion of String to double is not valid VB.net"

```
    a = Val(txtTotal.Text) * 0.03
    txt1month.Text = txtTotal.Text + a
```

Comment: `Dim a = Cdbl(txtTotal.Text) * 0.03`
`txt1month.Text = txtTotal.Text + a.ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are adding value of a double variable to a string. in this case casting is not done. so use like the following:

```
Dim a = Val(txtTotal.Text) * 0.03
txt1month.Text = CStr(Val(txtTotal.Text) + a)
```

Comment: And this is a very good example why you should use `&` to concatenate strings instead of `+`.